# would you use a cheap 70 amp stick welder for an exhaust pipe?

Tags: exhaust, welding

I've never welded before but how hard can it be right. You cut the old pipe out, go down to AutoZone and get yourself a new pipe and some adapters, tac it in place and then weld it all together. Easy, right?

I found this welding machine for $60 so if all goes well I'll get the job done cheaper than I would taking it to an exhaust shop and I'll get a welding machine out of the deal.

But I don't know anything about welding machines. Will a 70 amp stick welder be good enough?

[image]

Comment: Anything is possible. The first question you should ask yourself is, "*Do I know how to weld?*" If the answer is no, you're wasting your money. I pretty much already know the answer to the question I posit, and that would be no. If it was yes, I'd bet you'd already have a welder in your position, or would know this welder isn't going to do much for you.

Comment: you point the business end at the seam and pull the trigger? I have some spare metal laying around so I can practice once or twice before doing it.

Comment: If your exhaust pipe was 1/4" wall thickness I would give you a chance, however you will end up with a colander.

Comment: Welding well is surprisingly difficult.  Welding curved surfaces is even more difficult.  Welding thin material is even more difficult.  Welding overhead is even more...  Well you get the idea.  Good luck!  I'm not saying you cannot do it but be prepared for a colossal failure.  Also be very careful to dress appropriately.  Welding debris is VERY hot and will give you nasty burns when the little pieces fall into your shirt or shoes!

Comment: If it was a mig welder, then you would stand a better chance of getting something like a weld,, but a stick welder is another thing all together.   I hope you have plenty of thin steel to practice and practice on first.  With an exhaust, you are not only joining steel together, but you need it to be gas tight.

Comment: Couldn’t you just buy some clamp-on pipe joints, like these - https://www.merlinmotorsport.co.uk/p/jetex-sleeve-joint-double-2-inch-u065120

Comment: @jwh20 real men keep the weld pool going even if a bit of spatter falls in the boot…

Comment: "you point the business end at the seam and pull the trigger?" Yeah, sure. And then you figure out how to unweld the welder from the work you were trying to mend...

Comment: The guy at AutoZone said you had to weld it. But I gather clamps are actually the right way to do it. So I've decided to skip the welder and shop around for clamps. thanks @HandyHowie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually. Stick requires much practice and some skill and some knowledge of electrodes for material that thin. Unless you are already a welder , you will save time and money by paying more for a MIG welder. MIG does require set-up of welding parameters but when properly set up it is substantially easier to use. On the other hand if you are talking about a car or two, take it to a muffler shop. I apologize for repeating many of the comments. I forgot to mention ,you will be in AWS 6G position with thin steel, the most difficult category of all.

Comment: Well, I made my complete exhaust using gas... Keep hoping to buy a MIG but eventually...

Comment: Do you mean oxy-acetylene ?  That is a lot like work, slow and hot compared to TIG. I have melted some stick; One day the weld tech said try our new MIG ( which he had set-up) , it is so much easier than stick- no comparison.